# Does URLClassLoader use lazy loading?

Tags: java, jar, runtime, urlclassloader

I'm using URLClassLoader to load jars at runtime from a server URL (let's say: `http://jarsToBeLoaded/jars/`). I load `commons-collection.jar`, `commons-httpclient.jar` and `commons-io.jar`, for example. My question is: those jars are downloaded as soon as I invoke `addURL()` for each jar or as soon as I instantiate a class that is used within one of those jars (lazy)?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the behavior is not specified, so it will depend on your JVM how the URLs are treated. I have looked through the code of Open JDK 8u40. For that implementation there is no downloading of Jars when `addUrl()` is called. The call is delegated to `sun.misc.URLClassPath` for which you can see the implementation [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/misc/URLClassPath.java#URLClassPath.addURL%28java.net.URL%29):

```
public synchronized void addURL(URL url) {
    if (closed)
        return;
    synchronized (urls) {
        if (url == null || path.contains(url))
            return;

        urls.add(0, url);
        path.add(url);

        if (lookupCacheURLs != null) {
            // The lookup cache is no longer valid, since getLookupCache()
            // does not consider the newly added url.
            disableAllLookupCaches();
        }
    }
}
```

All the magic with loading classes from your Jar files will happen when you try to load your classes in those jars, using your custom classloader, for the first time and `java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass` will be called. I'm not sure if the Jars will actually be downloaded and cached somewhere or if the JVM will work with network streams all the time - the `URLClassPath` code is not easy to follow...